# SQL (snowflake) - how can I return 1 row from a join or use MAX in a second join from result of first

Tags: sql, join, subquery, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a large query that I have pasted parts of below.
I am wanting to use the result of the first join in my second join.

What I am trying to do get the last `session` that has a `lead_conversion` then I am getting all `sessions` in between then and the current row

This is the part I am struggling with

```
left join (
      select ss.id, ss.session_start, ss.lead_id
      from sessions ss
      inner join lead_conversions inner_lc on inner_lc.session_id = ss.id   
    ) prev_lc 
on prev_lc.lead_id = lc.lead_id 
and prev_lc.session_start::TIMESTAMP < s.session_start::TIMESTAMP

left join cte_sessions reset_prev_sess 
on reset_prev_sess.lead_id = lc.lead_id 
and reset_prev_sess.session_start::TIMESTAMP <= s.session_start::TIMESTAMP 
and (
  prev_lc.session_start::TIMESTAMP IS NULL 
  OR 
  reset_prev_sess.session_start::TIMESTAMP > prev_lc.session_start::TIMESTAMP
)
```

my issue is I cant just fetch the last `prev_lc` and I cant seem to use `max(prev_lc.session_start)`

I have tried grouping in first select and using `max` but this does not work as I believe this is ran before the on

```
left join (
      select max(ss.session_start) as session_start, max(ss.lead_id) as lead_id
      from sessions ss
      inner join lead_conversions inner_lc on inner_lc.session_id = ss.id   
      group by inner_lc.id
    ) prev_lc on prev_lc.lead_id = lc.lead_id
```

I have also tried using `max` in the second join but this give the error
`SQL compilation error: Invalid aggregate function in ON clause [MAX(CAST(PREV_LC.SESSION_START AS TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9)))]`

```
    left join cte_sessions reset_prev_sess 
        on reset_prev_sess.lead_id = lc.lead_id 
        and reset_prev_sess.session_start::TIMESTAMP <= s.session_start::TIMESTAMP 
        and (
          prev_lc.session_start::TIMESTAMP IS NULL 
          OR 
          reset_prev_sess.session_start::TIMESTAMP > max(prev_lc.session_start::TIMESTAMP)
        )
```

any help with this would be very appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

So I have found a solution for this if any one comes across this. I ended up just rethinking how I go about it.

I ended up adding a row number for each conversion

```
with cte_sessions as (
  select
  s.id
  ,s.lead_id
  ,s.session_start::TIMESTAMP as session_start
  ,CASE WHEN MAX(lc.id) IS NOT NULL
             then ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by  s.lead_id,  (CASE WHEN 
             MAX(lc.id) IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end)
                order by s.session_start
             )
  END as conversion_row
  from sessions s
  left join lead_conversions lc on lc.session_id = s.id
  group by s.id, s.session_start, s.lead_id, s.project_id, s.crawler_id
  order by s.session_start
)
```

The I just did this in the join

```
left join cte_sessions prev_lc on prev_lc.lead_id = lc.lead_id and prev_lc.conversion_row =  s.conversion_row - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly you are looking for to join with the last session start,so what you can do is to order by startsession in your subquery and limit to 1 record:

```
left join (
      select ss.id, ss.session_start, ss.lead_id
      from sessions ss
      inner join lead_conversions inner_lc on inner_lc.session_id = ss.id 
      order by ss.session_start desc
      limit 1  
    ) prev_lc
```

the rest of query stays untouched.

Comment: Sorry I should off stated I did try that one aswell. Unfortunately did not work. It seems the join no longer returns any results when adding that.

Comment: @Mewis, that can't be because of that . It's a left join . unless later on somewhere in your query you have an inner join depends on this and you don't have any values in lead_conversions for given session_id, which is not the issue with this method but rather your whole logic

Comment: I could be wrong here but is it because the sub query is ran first so by limiting to 1 result could mean there is only one result that is then used with the on clause?

Comment: @Mewis , you either have no result for join on  ss.id inside  the subquery which with or without limit 1 , it will not return anything. or you have 1 or more which with limit 1 it return only 1

Comment: on the second thought you might be right , which is what I tried to explain in my first comment . if this is what it is, then seems like you have to revise your logic.